# Android ERROR/PlayerDriver PVMFFailure on 3G but OK on Wifi

Tags: android, wifi, android-videoview, 3g

I'm using a `VideoView` to play online videos (with streaming, http://... style) in my application.
With 3G connectivity: on some videos (not all), i get immediatly the following error when the video starts : `ERROR/PlayerDriver(12039): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure`
When I switch to Wifi, all videos are fine.
What can I do to prevent this error?
Thanks.